# How to issue a JWT token with FastAPI so browser can save it and send it with future requests?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, fastapi

I have built an app with FastAPI that implements the OAuth2 flow exchanging username and password for Bearer token. The route that handles the authentication flow is /token. I have included the code below (Exhibit 1). It works fine in Swagger docs and I have verified that the subscriber can sign-in with username and password (Exhibit 2) and access their profile with the /grahaka/me route.

I added a route to accept username and password via HTML form (Exhibit 3). The /sign-in route's path operation function calls the /token path and POSTs form-data. This method works but returns the token in the response body (Exhibit 4).

Is it possible to send the Bearer token (JWT) in a way that a browser recognizes it, saves it and sends it with future requests (like a cookie)? My question is whether this is possible within native capabilities of a browser, modifying only server-side code. Any guidance is appreciated.

(1.) The /token path operation accepts credentials and returns Bearer token.

```
@app.post("/token", tags=["Security"], summary="Generate token after verifying credentials presented.")
async def create_JWT_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    """
    Issue a token when the grahaka signs in with username and password.
    The username and password are passed through a form.
    Executes the steps as follows:
    1. Authenticates the grahaka with the credentials supplied.
    2. Create an access token.
    3. Return the token in the expected format per specification.
    """
    grahaka = authenticate.authenticate_grahaka(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not grahaka:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail="Issued no token.",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    token_JWT = authorize.create_access_token(
        data={"sub": form_data.username},
        expires_delta=timedelta(minutes=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES_MINUTES)
    )
    return {"access_token": token_JWT, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

(2.) The subscriber has signed-in and can view their profile.

[image: Signed-in successfully!]
(3.) The /sign-in path uses an HTML form to accept credentials and calls /token.

```
@app.get("/sign-in")
async def html_form_auth():
    form_body = """
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="/token" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    <body>
    """
    pass_unbreakable = """
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=form_body)
```

(4.) The Bearer token is returned in response body. How to send the token so the browser can save it and send back with future requests?
[image: Token sent in response body.]

Comment: It it up to your front-end javascript code to handle the JWT and send it in subsequent requests. If you wish for it to be automatic, cookies (as you noted) would be the answer.

Comment: For js, this can be also useful https://stackoverflow.com/q/69769475/4859057