# How to store JWT from Post-Response and send it in HTML-forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, jwt

I want to send a JWT with the uploaddata when the user has logged in. To get it, I first need to use the LogIn Form. When I click on the loginButton, the function login() is called to make the post request with the formdata and waits for the response to retrieve the JWT, but an error indicating CORS-Header is missing is shown in the console at login-function "const json = await data.json();". However, i am able to see the token in the developer console.

Then when using the upload form, the JWT needs to be send as the authorauation header with the uploaded images as body. I want to accomplish this with plain javascript. This is what I have so far:

```
<form id="loginform">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="loginButton" type="submit">
</form>
    
<form id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="images" name="images" multiple data-max="5" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" >
    <input id="sendImagesButton" type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    const loginform = document.getElementById("loginform");
    loginform.addEventListener('submit', login);
    async function login(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login", {
            method: "POST",
            body: new FormData(this)
        });
        const json = await data.json();
        alert("test jwt retrieved");
        localStorage.setItem("token", json.access_token);
    }
    const pdfform = document.getElementById("uploadform");
    pdfform.addEventListener('submit', convert_to_pdf);
    function convert_to_pdf(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/convert_to_pdf", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Authorization': ' Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
            },
            body: new FormData(this)
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see(not that much) i can say that the process of the authentication with JWT should be:

- Send a POST request with the data you want in the token payload
- In the server create the token
- Send back the token(should be a single string, check it)

Now that you have access to the token on the client-side you can save it in the local or session storage([`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)).

Another option would be send the token on every request through cookies. It really depends on you.

EDIT: once you get the token back from the login request and you save it in the storage you have it available from anywhere in the client code, however the only way of sending it to the server via the update form(except using an hidden input) would be, in the script:

```js
document.querySelector('#uploadform').addEventListener('submit', e => {
 // here you can access and manage your form value and also of course access the token value
 // to send it to client you can use something like axios so you would do
 e.preventDefault(); // that prevent the form to send its request
 // now send you request manually with your data for e.g.
 axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/convert_to_pdf', /* your data here */)
})
```

Comment: I already have the implementation of the JWT flow, as i get it in the response message of the login-request. I wanted to know how to store it instead and send it whenever i perform the upload-request. But thanks for the localStorage hint.

Comment: Just updated my answer, take a look

Answer (score 0):

Default browser action for form submit by POST is to render response content. If it is not desired behavior you'll have to perform request from JS manually e.g. by using [`onsubmit`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) attribute.

I found tutorial about that on [Mozilla developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript).

Also you'll have to store JWT somewhere, maybe [local-storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), when read it back and add it to `Authorization` header in next request, also done through JS and not standard browser submit.

Comment: Hi thanks! I updated my question since it is not working. the test alert is not showing either